# Sencha Touch get draggable element position

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2, panel, draggable

Is there any way to get the current vertical position of a panel while dragging it?

I have something like this:

```
Ext.define("App.DashboardDrawer",
{
  extend: 'Ext.Panel',
  xtype: 'dashboarddrawer',

  config: {
    cls: 'w-drawer',
    height: '380px',
    zIndex: 99999,
    id: 'drawer-container',
    docked: 'bottom',
    draggable:{
      direction:'vertical',
      constraint: {
        min: { x: 0, y: 0 },
        max: { x: 0, y: 338 }
      }
    },
    listeners:{
      drag: function(list, idx, target, record, evt) {
        // I'd like to get the current position of the panel here

      }
    },
...
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you inspect the evt object in the drag function ?

Comment: It says it's undefined in that case.

Comment: That's because the signature is wrong. Try this drag( draggable, evt, offsetX, offsetY, eOpts )

Comment: That's an object but I still can't find anything helpful there. Also, offsetY is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It works for me.

```
        Ext.define('Stackoverflow.view.Demo', {
        extend: 'Ext.Panel',
        alias: 'widget.demo',

        config:
        {  
            draggable:{
              direction:'vertical',
              constraint: {
                min: { x: 0, y: 0 },
                max: { x: 0, y: 338 }
              },
              listeners: {
                    drag: function( draggable, evt, offsetX, offsetY, eOpts ) {
                         console.log( offsetX);
                    }
              }}
        }
        });
```

Comment: offsetX? I think I actually need offsetY since the dragging is vertically but offsetY is undefined.